# how to use one jar that depends on another jar

Tags: java, jar

suppose in my application "MyClass", I want to use class A in jar1, and some part of class A depends on some class B in jar2. If I put both jar1 and jar2 on my classpath and run MyClass, it still complains that class B can not be found.

Could anybody tell me how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: George Lucas is on the phone, he wants his jar jar back.

Comment: Show HOW you put the jars in your classpath.  Also, are you SURE jar2 really contains class B?  What are the fully qualified class names of A and B, and is the reference from A to B fully qualified?

Answer (score 3):

The `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable is **ignored** when you use `java` command with `-jar` argument. Specify it using `-classpath` argument or its shorthand `-cp`. Alternatively you can also specify it in the `class-path` entry of the `MANIFEST.MF` file of the JAR file which you execute.

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered this being a problem, but have you tried putting jar2 before jar1 in the class path order? I think it's more likely that jar2 is simply not being included properly. Can you post the classpath setting?

Also, you may want to open up jar2 (it's just a zip file), and verify that the class you think is in there is in fact in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think that including jar2.jar in the jar1 `MANIFEST.MF` would probably work, provided they're in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned providing the name of needed jar in the MANIFEST.MF file of the jar that you invoke is one way to resolve your problem.

During jar file (the one you invoke first) creation you can specify the  manifest file which contains this detail so that it gets bundled with your jar.

The [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) has a section on how to specify the Manifest file during the jar creation.

If you are using Ant as your build tool you can use the Ant task  [Manifest](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html) to create a  manifest file. You can use the Manifest file thus created in the Ant task that builds your jar.

Also check this [link](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html) which provides more details about the Manifest file.