# Sending parameter to main class function in jar

Tags: java, jar

i have make one **jar** file called **GetOfferSoftware** in that jar i have Main class called **Offer**
and this Offer class contain following function

```
           getOffer(String name1,String name2){

           }//Offer class function
```

now  i want to call this function from **another java program** that not related to GetOfferSoftware jar
So my question is how to access and sent parameter to getOffer() function from another java class .
Guys Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `GetOfferSoftware.jar` to the other projects class path, import the `Offer` class into it call `getOffer`

Comment: There's just not enough information here.  How are the two jars related?  How is `getOffer` declared? etc., etc.

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet that you have tried?

Comment: Actually there is only one jar that is GetOfferSoftware.jar and another is only java program called FinalOffer.java in oracle database and now i want to call and send parameter to Offer class (in GetOfferSoftware.jar) to retrieve related pdf's from database

Comment: if getOffer method is public, i think it does not matter..

Comment: Obviously, if the visibility is `public` he only needs to add the .jar to his classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use classes and methods from another jar

**1)** You need to include them in the classpath. In essence you add them as libraries/references.

See: [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

**2)** The method in question needs to have the appropriate modifiers related to visibility, e.g. to not be protected or private.

See: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

--A)If the method is protected: your own jar/.class must have the same package declaration.

--B)If the method is `static` you can directly call it.

**3)** If the method is not `static` you need to create a new Object of the class the method is declared in, and call it.

See: [Java: when to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)

```
Object whatever = new MyClass();
whatever.getOffer(paramsGoHere);
```

**See also:**

- [how to use one jar that depends on another jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905104/how-to-use-one-jar-that-depends-on-another-jar)

### Update

**[how to include libraries in java without using an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112607/how-to-include-libraries-in-java-without-using-an-ide)**

[Adding External JARs to Eclipse Buildpath](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java))

[Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) (via command line)

Comment: Actually there is only one jar that is GetOfferSoftware.jar and another is only java program called FinalOffer.java in oracle database and now i want to call and send parameter to Offer class (in GetOfferSoftware.jar) to retrieve related pdf's from database

Comment: u r right meewoK but i want to access this getOffer() function from another java program not through any jar, so how to import GetOfferSoftware.jar in that java program FinalOffer.java

Comment: See: Adding External JARs to Eclipse Buildpath . You need to add also the `class` hosting the `getOffer` method as an import. e.g. `import org.whatever.Offer`. And if your method is not static call, `new offer().getOffer(paramsGoHere)`. If your method is static, just call offer.getOffer(paramsGoHere)`. Offer will be your class name.

Comment: Thank you frnd, i have FinalOffer class in oracle database and GetOfferSoftware.jar in oracle database and now i want to access that Offer class through FinalOffer so what i do, give me some code to implement this .

Comment: Do u know how to call jar from oracle database

Comment: Yes surely, I have implemented one project that is use to generate One final Pdf using several pdf according to user condition. for that i have develop one java desktop application and it works better. but my client have oracle apex and now i want to develop the same thing in oracle apex. for that i have use following logic , i will put that jar file in database and then i will send some parameter(user selection) to that jar main class and will generate pdf on logical directory. thats why i was confuse how to do that...if its possible then plese mail me u r email id on srdeshmukh786@gmail.com

Comment: u dont know about this stuff. and plz mail me u r email id

Comment: I'm saying this is a completely different question. You should include all information in a question so that other users who want to ask the same thing will be able to find it. Once you make a new question I can answer :) .