# how to call the main class inside jar from oracle function

Tags: java, oracle, jar

I have one jar in oracle database and i want to call that jar and send some parameters to the main class function

```
    public getOffer(String name 1,String name2){

    } // function that in main class in jar
```

how to implement this.  Waiting for helpful replies
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Don't just repeat the same question over and over again. Improve the first one insted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021844/sending-parameter-to-main-class-function-in-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a Java method inside the oracle database you have to make this method `static` (like a `main(String[])` method.

After that you have to create a PL/SQL-wrapper:

```
create or replace function get_offer(name1 in varchar2, name2 in varchar2) return varchar2
is language java name 'MyClass.getOffer(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
```

See also the [Oracle Documention](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm).

Comment: but main class is in jar and this jar  in oracle database. so This wrapper will work ?

Comment: @SURJA I you loaded the jar with `loadjar` it works.

Comment: Thanks Uwe Plonus , i will try thanks again and please give me some shortcut description or any link about how to load jar using loadjar and please mail me u r email id to srdeshmukh786@gmail.com to make some work deal

Comment: @SURJA Please follow the link to the Oracle documetation I gave in my answer.

Comment: i read the given oracle documentation but there is no any loadjar , there is a loadjava so will it work if i will use loadjava to load jar file into oracle database

Comment: @SURJA I meant `loadjava`.

Comment: thanks, if the main jar contains another jar then how i will write the loadjava , i read oracle documentation but i m confused..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

import that jar in your program and create object of that class and simple call that method by object.methodname and necessary parameter that methods required